# A wrinkle in time

Tags: riddle, word

I'm like a giant ball on a cosmic trampoline.
All bend to me and circle closer
You could think of me as evil if you wish
Since I destroy all those who come to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you

> a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole)?

I'm like a giant ball on a cosmic trampoline.<sup>1</sup>
All bend to me and circle closer<sup>2</sup>
You could think of me as evil if you wish<sup>3</sup>
Since I destroy all those who come to me<sup>4</sup>

> Per the linked article, *"A black hole is a region of spacetime exhibiting such strong gravitational effects that nothing—including particles and electromagnetic radiation such as light—can escape from inside it."*
>
>   *"As predicted by general relativity, the presence of a mass deforms spacetime in such a way that the paths taken by particles bend towards the mass. At the event horizon of a black hole, this deformation becomes so strong that there are no paths that lead away from the black hole."*
>
>  I don't know how to describe this concisely (nor do I understand how to recognize the scientific language in the linked article that says this, at a glance), but my understanding of a black hole is that it's **[1]** a mass so dense that everything curves around it, including gravity—like a bowling ball on a trampoline. Anything coming near enough to it is **[4]** sucked in—*"[spaghettified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification)"*—by extreme tidal forces, rending it such that its constituent atoms no longer coalesce to anything recognizable.
>
>  **[2]** OK so I couldn't think of a clever way to explain this one, but, again, from my understanding, when things are pulled by gravitational forces toward a body in space, they sort of "spiral" toward it; in a lot of cases, they end up a distance away from the body, propelled eternally around it, but in the case of a black hole, they are sucked in rather than falling into an "orbit".
>
>  **[3]** Uhh I don't know if I'm expected to explain this or not, but a) 'black' and 'darkness' are [cultural signifiers of "bad" or "evil" things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black#Darkness_and_evil), b) black holes destroy things (destruction is generally considered bad, dunno if I need a citation here or if we can all agree that it's not the most popular noun at Word Thanksgiving), and c) black holes specifically [find themselves](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2079923/Nasa-finds-evil-eye-watching-Earth-deep-space.html) [mentioned near](https://www.quora.com/Are-black-holes-evil) [the concept of "evil"](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110324105144AATdfJE) fairly often
>
>  <sub>Please forgive my non-sciencey explanation words.</sub>

Comment: incorrect. Black hole is not a ball.

Comment: @JayeshJain [Here](http://www.iflscience.com/space/black-holes-might-be-harmless) and [here](http://www.firstpost.com/living/nasa-finding-confirms-indian-theory-black-holes-are-ultra-hot-balls-of-fire-2519236.html)

Comment: @JayeshJain The standard explanation of how large masses warp space-time is to compare them to a large ball on a taut sheet of rubber, or a trampoline.

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat : yes I totally aggree with that!! but I am not sure all blackholes are ball like structure.

Answer (score 8):

Answer is

> SUN

I'm like a giant ball on a cosmic trampoline.

> The Sun is indeed a giant ball and a star large enough that about 1,300,000 planet Earths can fit inside of it.

All bend to me and circle closer

> When the star is formed, it bends the curavature of space and time(the fabric of the cosmos). Because of this curvature, we feel the force of what we know today as GRAVITY. All the planets orbit around curvature formed by the SUN. Thank you Mr.Einstien :)

You could think of me as evil if you wish
Since I destroy all those who come to me

> For all the damage it has done to the planets that are not in goldilock region(eg mercury,mars), Life has literally ceased and the planets near to the sun are nothing more than hot rocky bodies .Its better if you stay away from it, anything that comes near it burns because of extreme tempratures.(5,778 K - surface temperature).

A wrinkle in time

> The title can also be justified. According to the people who study space, there will be a time when the sun will run out of its fuel and its core will collapse. The Sun is about 4.5 billion years old. It has used up about half of its nuclear fuel (hydrogen). In about 5 billion years from now, the sun will begin to die. However, for our massive massive universe which has billions and billions of stars, this is just another star that will die. So its just a wrinkle in time. Not to mention, if sun dies,we also die :) .But I think we still got plenty of time(4.5bln yrs) and who knows if humans could colonise some other planet in future.

Comment: incorrect. Sun is not a ball. :p

Comment: @manshu http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/info/press-releases/RoundSun/

Answer (score -1):

> Is it a tesseract?

Someone's answer "The standard explanation of how large masses warp space-time is to compare them to a large ball on a taut sheet of rubber, or a trampoline." hinted at it... Plus it is in the book several times.